# Add values to an unknown number of elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am making a project in PHP and I created multiple variables as following:

```
$errors = array();
$errors['firstname'] = 'Enter First Name'
$errors['lastname'] = 'Enter Last Name'
$errors['age'] = 'Enter Age'
```

And I am having an other array `$_SESSION['flash']['error']` to display the errors in the projects.

What I want, it is to get an array like this: `$_SESSION['flash']['error'] = ('Enter First Name', 'Enter Last Name', 'Enter Age')`

Kindly help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$_SESSION['flash']['error'] = [ $errors['firstname'] , $errors['lastname'], $errors['age'] ];`?

Comment: Yes something last this but by using a loop if possible because the number of elements of `$errors` is unknown

Comment: To set in a loop, and checking to see if the value is set via post, you could do `$required = ['firstname','lastname','age']; foreach($required as $key){ if(empty($_POST[$key'])){ $_SESSION['flash']['error'][] = $errors[$key]; }`. Using an array of your required keys `$required` from your `$errors`, you could check if the value is `empty()` and add to your `$_SESSION` array

Comment: Or, if you just want to pass all of `$errors` into `$_SESSION['flash']['error']`, a similar loop - `foreach($errors as $error) { $_SESSION['flash']['error'][] = $error; }`

Comment: Thanks for providing your help. Post your answer for me to mark it correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate the `$_SESSION['flash']['error']` with the error messages for the values that are not set, you can do it with a loop. Here I would create an array of all the required keys, then looping over those keys, check if the value is empty (in this example with `$_POST`) and then insert the error message into the array -

```
// array of required keys
$required = ['firstname','lastname','age']; 

// loop over the required keys
foreach($required as $key){ 

    // check if that key value is empty
    if(empty($_POST[$key])){ 

        // if the value was empty, insert the corresponding error message into the array
        $_SESSION['flash']['error'][] = $errors[$key]; 
    }
}
```

but, if you simply just want to add all the error messages, without any conditionals, a simple loop would do this -

```
foreach($errors as $error) { 
    $_SESSION['flash']['error'][] = $error; 
}
```

As an alternative, you could just loop over the `$error` array. This has the same result as the 1st example, with the cleanness of the 2nd example. Here we check the `$errors` keys, and then add the `$errors` values.

```
foreach($errors as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($_POST[$key])){
        $_SESSION['flash']['error'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeiLionel I added a simpler example, that just loops over the `$errors` array, and checks the key, similar to the 1st example, with the cleaner/simpler version of the 2nd example. sometimes I overthink things, not remembering to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

This code could run . . .

```
$errors = array();
$errors['firstname'] = 'Enter First Name';
$errors['lastname'] = 'Enter Last Name';
$errors['age'] = 'Enter Age';

$_SESION['flash']['error'] = implode(", ", $errors);

var_dump($_SESSION);

# the result is: 

# array(1) { ["flash"]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> string(42) "Enter First     Name,Enter Last Name,Enter Age" } }
```